# How to change the object file name through a CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I am new to CMake. In my current project specific directory c file generated object file name need to be modified as below

Ex: foo_lib.c     ---> foo_AR_lib.o

```
foo1_lib.c    ---> foo1_AR_lib.o

foo2_lib.c    ---> foo2_AR_lib.o
```

I tried using the `file(RENAME <oldname> <newname>)` but the original c file is modifying.
So, could you please help on this, the possibilities using any other CMake methods we can achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does `set_property(SOURCE foo1_lib.c APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "-o foo1_AR_lib.o")` work on gcc? Or, if you run MSVC does `set_property(SOURCE foo1_lib.c APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "/Fo foo1_AR_lib.o")` work?

Comment: I would just `add_custom_command(OUTPUT foo1_AR_lib.c COMMAND cp foo1_lib.c  foo1_AR_lib.c)`  and then would just use `add_something(...  foo1_AR_lib.c)`, cmake will just compile the `_AR_` version.

Comment: I tried this approch and some how its not working .... i am compiling for msvc project set_property(SOURCE foo1_lib.c APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_OPTIONS "/Fo foo1_AR_lib.o")

Comment: Would you pls explain a bit **why** you need to rename object files?

Comment: @Kumar Can you add the console error output to your question. "some how its not working" is a very vague description for an error. A typical object extension on MSVC is `.obj` Maybe you need to use that. If you open the generated solution from the Microsoft Visual Studio, right click on the source file and select `Properties` entry from the context menu. Under the `C/C++` entry there is an `Output Files` section, What value has the property `Output File Name`?

Comment: Just a small correction. The value for the `COMPILE_OPTIONS` property for MSVC must read `"/Fo\$(IntDir)foo1_AR_lib.obj"`

Comment: @vre: Adding **manual** compile option `-o foo1_AR_lib.o` is hardly a good (or even working) approach for change the name of **output** file. For CMake, object files are intermediate (not final), so would the manual option successfully changes the name of produced object file, CMake still expects the file of *original name* to be created. And if the object file with original name is not created, then linking (or archiving) stage would fail.

Comment: @Tsyvarev As the OP has not clarified his use case, we can only guess on it. @ Kumar What are you trying to do? Maybe there are a lot more easier ways to achieve what you are after.

Comment: I was going to suggest creating an `OBJECT` target for each object, then using `set_target_properties(MyFoo1 PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "foo1_AR_lib")` to change the output name. But `OUTPUT_NAME` property is *only* applied to library and executable targets...

Comment: @ gordan.sikic, @vre: I have a specific module, in that all the files name needs to be modified based on the type of build. if my build type is AR all the files in the module object files need to be modified as foo_AR_lib.o. If my build type is IR the object file needs to modify as foo_IR_lib.o. So here the original source code should not change as the build types are may configurations.